# Making system calls to bash from gnuplot scripts in Ubuntu based distros

Tags: ubuntu, bash, gnuplot

My question is: How can I change the default shell of gnuplot? I want to change it in order to send stdout to bash.

This should be pretty easy, but I'm giving up. Here's why.

I'm running gnuplot ver. 4.6 patchlevel 3 on Lubuntu 13.10.

My default interactive shell is bash (Bourne-again shell), and Lubuntu's login shell seems to be dash (Debian Almquist shell). No problem with that.

But gnuplot is also using dash instead bash. This is what I got when I ask gnuplot:

```
gnuplot> system "echo $0"
sh
```

And then, when I ask my shell:

```
$ which sh
/bin/sh
$ ls -goh /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Dec 23 09:30 /bin/sh -> dash
```

The context of the problem: I'm generating several epslatex plots, and I need to change the includegraphics path of each one.

This shouldn't be a problem, it's nothing that sed and a loop can't solve, but calling sed or a bash script using the system call command of gnuplot didn't work for me. The last three lines of the last file are always missing. However, running the same from pure bash do a pretty clean job.

I also tried the opossite, calling gnuplot from a bash script, including print commands on the gnuplot script and trying to capture the std output of gnuplot to a bash variable, but it didn't work either. Trying the following line from bash, for example, returns messages to the std output, but doesn't store contents to the variable.

```
var=$(gnuplot plot.gnu)
```

I don't know whether this is a Lubuntu's or gnuplot's issue. I already solved my tex files problem with a workaround, but the gnuplot's shell thing is still bothering me.

So I'm asking in it a general way: ¿How can I change the default shell of gnuplot? ¿Is it possible? Maybe it can be useful for someone else. ;)

**Edited on 2016-08-03**

The original question was about how to run bash commands and scripts from gnuplot using a system call (using the `system` command). However, the solution I proposed for this question was to change the original system shell of the distribution, dash, to the shell I knew, bash.

Changing the system shell to bash might affect the system's overall performance.

Comment: Really, this is two questions:  The actual objective that you have, and how to change the shell that is spawned by `gnuplot`.  Guess which one is [chocolate-covered](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/put-down-the-chocolate-covered-banana.html).  I suggest that you expand upon your _actual objective_, with more details.  Then someone can tell you that [there's a TeX StackExchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109277/).  (-:

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm new here and I'm kind new to StackExchange, but I think my question fits well here. My main question is about how to change the shell of gnuplot. I can make a workaround for my other problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I found was to configure bash as the default shell for the whole system (Ubuntu).

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure dash
```

This line opens a ncurses assistant, which asks about letting dash be the default system shell.

If one answers **no**, then bash is set as the default system shell.

After that, my gnuplot scripts worked flawlessly.

**Edited on 2016-08-03**

Take into account that this solution is changing the default shell of your Linux distribution, and it might affect system's overall performance.

Comment: Didn't work for me. After running this command, `ls -l /bin/sh` shows `/bin/sh -> bash` but `system "echo $0"` still outputs `sh`.

Comment: @arekolek are you sure it didn't work? You can verify that `sh` is `/bin/sh` and bash is `/bin/bash` using the command `which`. The list command is telling you that `sh` is a symbolic link to `bash`, so every time `sh` is called, then `bash` is used. Unless you want `dash` to be called instead of `bash`, which is the opposite of this solution. On the other hand, system "echo $0" always print `sh` regardless of whether is pointing to `dash` or `bash`.

Comment: I think you are right, I was fooled by the `sh` instead of `bash`. I guess running `!ls -go $(which $0)` is a better test than `!echo $0`. I hoped that I could use functions from my `~/.zshrc` inside `gnuplot`, but apparently it is not sourced at that moment.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution for this old thread is to call bash explicitely. However, this needs (horrible) quoting:

```
gnuplot> !bash -c "echo -e 1{1,2,3}"
```

or, as plot data,

```
plot "< bash -c \"tail -q -n +2 /usr/vera/exos_log/regulate_gspr.log.old.{3,2,1} | grep '^20..-'\"" using 0:2 with lines
```

I choose examples which exploit advanced features of bash and will not work with dash.